# SignatureDoesNotMatch error with Amazon S3 and pre-signed URLs php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I'm trying to GET a pre-signed URL for an object from S3 using php. I keep getting the SignatureDoesNotMatch error. Below is my code.

```
$client = S3Client::factory(array(
            'key'    => getenv('S3_KEY'),
            'secret' => getenv('S3_SECRET'),
            'region' => 'us-east-1', // @todo does this matter?
        ));

$presignedUrl = $client->getObjectUrl(getenv('S3_BUCKET'), $id, '+5 minutes');

return $presignedUrl;
```

I then get the correctly formatted url returned however, when I try to POST a photo with the URL from a third party app, I get the following error the SignatureDoesNotMatch error. Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong here?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean, *when I try to POST a photo with the URL from a third party app*? You are trying to provide the app with the signed URL where the app should obtain the source image, and the app is trying to fetch the image from S3?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me so quickly! I want to provide the app with the signed URL to give authorization for the app to post an image directly through S3. Does that make a bit more sense?

Comment: I've read that it might be the incorrect `key` and `secret` or that you have to add the Content-Type, but even double checking these were correct, it still doesn't work. Any other ideas?